# Salt Minion cannot reach Salt Master at port 4505. What workaround can I use?

Tags: salt-stack

I've a Salt Master server and some Minions that work well. All the configuration is by default.

I've one Salt Minion in a really strict network. Running

```
 nc -v -z salt.master.ip.addr 4505
```

returns

```
4505 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

And obviously it cannot connect to the Master. I'm not an expert on network topics and I haven't found a nice workaround. What can you suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port the master listens on with the `publish_port` option in the master config.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#publish-port

You would also have to change the port the minion uses to connect to the master:  https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/minion.html#master-port-syntax

Have you checked the firewall on your Salt Master?